# Why am I being asked to review Low Quality Posts filtered by [android]?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

[image: LQP filtered by android tag]

/review is suggesting that I filter my LQP reviews by [android].  I have only answered 6 questions tagged [android] for a total of 3 score.  Those questions were not really about Android; I'm certainly not an Android expert.  So why would I be any better at reviewing Android LQP?

Comment: That's the tag with more items....

Comment: So it isn't adaptive?  I've never seen that recommendation before, so I assumed it was a new feature based on the new recommendation system.

Comment: Well, I presume that it appears after `tasks-with-tag > X` and going by the number I presume someone went trough the android tag flagging whatever was bad.

Comment: Well someone has to take the sewage overflow.  Better you than I :)